# Prevent termination of UWP app on relaunch

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp, lifecycle, background-task

We have a UWP app, which has 3 registered background tasks, one is an **app-trigerred** task which keeps running in the background until failure.
The approach is to restore the last saved state which is kept within the background processor object, that has not failed until now, it works with those data kept until the last moment of background activity and returns data if the UI content is not gone yet (by swiping the app away from recent apps).
The only problem is when the main thread is gone and the app has to relaunch on activation, last instance of the app is **terminated**, which means the background object is gone too and we cannot restore anything.
Is there any wrong implemention which can cause this, is there any way to prevent it?
**Clarification:** The background task is getting user's location each 5 seconds and sending it to the server. There are no logs, but using Debug Output, I've ensured that the BGtask is running until relaunch, which it's suspended and terminated. An application trigger is fired while entering background and the task is forced to shut down while leaving background.
Thanks.

Comment: Bump? may I bump? Please help! I'm stuck with no solution here.

Comment: You got to put your state in some persistant storage, like localsettings or a file.

Comment: Is that the only way? Is it in a normal lifecycle to terminate the app before relaunching it?

Comment: What's the trigger you are using for the background task? Did you use the application trigger? What's the background task doing? Did you write logs for the background task?

Comment: @Sunteen-MSFT I've updated the post with the information you requetsed.

Comment: OK,  I saw it. In that thing, what thing you want to prevent?  Did you want to prevent the app terminated?  Why your app terminated? Did you want to prevent terminate or restore the app and the background task?

Comment: @Sunteen-MSFT Yes, I want to keep the HTTP session alive. For that I need to restore the Http client and data stored in the background task into foreground on relaunch. Actually, the reason of termination is the exact thing I'm after.

Comment: Bump!? Help. am I missing any important information?

Comment: "Background Task is getting user's location every 5 seconds" - This doesn't work => you got only limited cpu time in a background task and timer trigger needs to be greater than 15 minutes - you can save things when closing the app by overriding the OnSuspended event => there you have 5 seconds of cpu time

Comment: Well, i'm not using a time trigger. I'm using an application trigger. It starts immediately after getting off from the application, going to background. Then it sleeps each 5 seconds, and getting the location data and sending them to server, which is not really heavy task to be done.

Comment: You can save your states and data when [OnSuspending](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242341). Next time relaunch just resume them.

Comment: So, that's what I'm going for, but I need the session state, it contains important information, and if the Client object is gone, session is gone too. I also need to warn the client about connection failures, which will be somehow impossible if happens within the suspension progress.

Comment: @AnnaSB Using the mvvm pattern and saving the viewmodel in OnSuspending then loading it next time starting

Comment: It sounds like you really should be learning about HTTP (which happens to be stateless), instead of asking to prevent your app from entering a state, where this matters. You can't prevent the user from forcefully closing your app (which they likely will, once they observe the battery drain), or the device losing power altogether. You need to address your **real** issue, and stop worrying about **one** of its manifestations.

Comment: Actually, a user force close is very welcome, as it means they have agreed to leave the session, but the problem is from elsewhere, Windows is terminating the app on relaunch, and it's neither what I what nor user is comfortable with. Simply, the HTTP session contains credentials for terminating the sesison inside the web-app (not talking about HttpSession here), that's why I want the connection to be kept alive, so users can notify the server whether they intentionally want to quit the session. I'm currently using a save-load pattern, but that way user is losing session data.

Answer (score 1):

Try to store the data you need to when the app is suspending using the

```
private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
    var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
    //TODO: Save application state and stop any background activity
    deferral.Complete();
}
```

In the app.xaml.cs file. Don't you think that saving the user's position every five seconds and saving in on your databases is an invasion of their privacy. I don't know what your app is about but I don't see any good reason to know your user's position every 5s.